# Windows batch file to block multiple hosts (using list)

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to add multiple lines to the hosts file if they're not existing. My code works great but I want to do it for a list of 30 entries and thats where I don't know how to handle it. I thought about a list and a for-loop but I don't know how.

```
@ECHO OFF

ECHO Checking administrator right.

OPENFILES >NUL 2>&1
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (

    ECHO Administrator right detected.
    ECHO.
    ECHO Hosts file : %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
    ECHO.

    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

        SET BLOCKLINE=127.0.0.1 example.com
        ECHO Checking : !BLOCKLINE!
        FIND /C /I "!BLOCKLINE!" "%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts" >NUL 2>NUL
        IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 (
            ECHO Line not found, adding to the hosts file.
            ECHO !BLOCKLINE!>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
        ) ELSE (
            ECHO Line found.
        )
        ECHO.

    ENDLOCAL

    ECHO Patching is completed.
    ECHO Check hosts file if you want to see the result.
    ECHO.

) ELSE (

    ECHO Administrator right not detected.
    ECHO You need admin right to use this hosts patch!
    ECHO.

)

PAUSE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic for loop will suffice.
Define the lines to test in the loop set

```
For %%L in (
    "127.0.0.1 example1"
    "127.0.0.30 example30"
) Do (
    ECHO Checking : %%~L
    FIND /C /I "%%~L" "%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts" >NUL 2>NUL
    IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 (
        ECHO Line not found, adding to the hosts file.
        >>"%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts" ECHO %%~L
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO Line found.
    )
)
```

Comment: when I open a cmd as admin and execute the batch it works. When I just rightklick and execute as admin it does not work. What the hell?

Comment: The actual reason really is my antivirus software Kaspersky. With Kaspersky off even a double click works with my admin acc.